# Java split method is not working properly?

Tags: java, string

This is my piece of code I want to split the string with `$` symbol but the string doesn't getting spitted.

***Here is my code:***

```
   String str="first$third$nine%seventh";
   String s[]=str.split("$");
   System.out.println(s[0]);
```

The output is the whole string:

> first$third$nine%seventh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common thing in string class. Ans this has been already asked and answers are available in stackoverflow.

You should escape the regular expression symbol in split method. There are so many characters like $,?,*,^,+ which should be escaped while using as a parameter in split method.

Comment: Not `"`.  It's not special.

Comment: Ys david its not special but we have to escape it while using as a parameter otherwise there will be compilation error

Comment: No, we have to escape it when including it in a string literal.  We don't have to escape it when using it as a parameter, unless it's included in a string literal.

Comment: `"` shouldn't be listed with the regex characters. If you do have to escape it, you escape it differently (single backslash).

Comment: thankyou David, Kavi for this information. thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 7):

[`split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) as an argument. `$` is a magic character in regex.

If you escape it with backslashes, it will be used as a normal character instead of a special regex character.

```
String s[]=str.split("\\$");
```